# I want generate all possible rules generated from list items

Tags: python-2.7

Note: I'm working in python on this.

For example given a list:

`list = ['E','D','F']`

I want to generate all rules of the following forms:

```
['E']     --> ['D','F']
['D']     --> ['E','F']
['F']     --> ['E','D']
['E','D'] --> ['F']
['E','F'] --> ['D']
['D','F'] --> ['E']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer of Dan H [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements) and at the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Code should look something like:

```
import itertools

letters = ['E','D','F']
for i in range(len(letters)+1):
    for j in itertools.combinations(letters, i):
        print j
```

This provides the following output:

```
()
('E',)
('D',)
('F',)
('E', 'D')
('E', 'F')
('D', 'F')
('E', 'D', 'F')
```

If you don't want the output `()` just use `for i in range(1,len(letters)+1):`

Comment: I don't want combinations but i want output in the form of rules as i mentioned above in my questions...

Comment: @Vijesh - What do you mean by "form of rules" ? Care to elaborate or provide a link to documentation